# TFS 2015 Integration with SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2016

Is TFS 2015 is compatible with SharePoint 2016? Google search shows it is not compatible but didn't find any updated reference.

Comment: Just like Daniel mentioned above, in TFS 2015 and upper version, the dashboard features has added to team project home page, so you could start to use [TFS dashboard](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/dashboards) instead of using SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not compatible. The TFS integration with sharepoint is, at this point, more or less abandoned in favor of more flexible built-in dashboards, graphing, and reporting capabilities. You can still use Sharepoint for document management without having it explicitly integrated with an instance of TFS. I always recommend examining what you're using Sharepoint for in the context of TFS. I think you'll find that it's unnecessary to have it integrated.